DllNotFoundException: Vuforia Wrapper assembly <unknown assembly> type: <unknown type> member: null
I am trying to build a desktop PC application that uses the webcam and Vuforia in Unity. Everything works fine in the Editor, but after I build and run the application, the webcam image does not appear. And it presents the following error:Error presents in development console
I tried updating to the latest version of Unity, but I still wasn't able to run the compilation capturing the webcam image, I've also already configured the capabilities in unity. I expected the application to run capturing the webcam image in real time.

Which platform are you developing for? Note that Vuforia Engine supports UWP development only (not Win32).
